# Constructing lists by applying functions to another list

Tags: list-manipulation, functions

Suppose f is a function of two variables: $f = f(x,y)\quad$ and $L$ is a list. Could someone help me in defining a list of the form:
$D = \{f(x,y)\ |\ x \in L,\ y \in L\}$

I tried this:

```
D = List[ f[x,y], {x,y} ∈ KroneckerProduct[L,L]]
```

But I got syntax errors.

Comment: What syntax errors did you get? It could just be that you were trying to assign to `D` which is a defined symbol already in Mathematica.

Comment: Also I formatted your code. You might want to read [this page](http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com/editing-help) which shows how to do it yourself.

Comment: Are you looking for functioning code or are you trying to typeset something?

Comment: Sorry about ambiguities. The syntax error was:

`D = Table[f[x, y], {x, y} \[Element] Tuples[L, 2]]`

`Table::itform: Argument {x,y}\[Element]Tuples[L,2] at position 2 does not have the correct form for an iterator. >>`

where
`L = {{0, 0, 0, 1}, {0, 1, 1, 0}}`.

In my question, i didn't need x and y to be the same elements, so `Tuples[L,2]` is more appropriate.

I am looking for a functioning code.

Let me state it simply, similar to:

`Flatten[Table[f[x,y], {x, 0, 10}, {y, 0, 10}]]`

can't we have a similar definition where x and y belong to different lists, say L1 and L2 respectively ?

Comment: In future questions could you please post the code that you actually used? Apparently you used `Table` instead of `List`, `Tuples` instead of `KroneckerProduct` and x and y need not equal vs. need to be equal.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your original definition of D can be given with these lines:

```
In[1]:= L = {a, b, c, d};
In[2]:= Outer[f, L, L] // Flatten
Out[2]= {f[a, a], f[a, b], f[a, c], f[a, d], f[b, a], f[b, b], 
 f[b, c], f[b, d], f[c, a], f[c, b], f[c, c], f[c, d], f[d, a], 
 f[d, b], f[d, c], f[d, d]}]
```

If f is symmetric, then you can:

```
In[3]:= SetAttributes[f, Orderless]
In[4]:= Outer[f, L, L] // Flatten // Union
Out[4]= {f[a, a], f[a, b], f[a, c], f[a, d], f[b, b], f[b, c], 
 f[b, d], f[c, c], f[c, d], f[d, d]}
```

Answer (score 8):

If `f` is a function of two-variables, a direct way to define your list (we call it `Dlt` since `D` is a built-in `Mathematica` function) would be this :

```
L = {a, b, c, d, e};

Dlt = f @@@ Tuples[ L, 2]
```

> ```
> {f[a, a], f[a, b], f[a, c], f[a, d], f[a, e],
>  f[b, a], f[b, b], f[b, c], f[b, d], f[b, e],
>  f[c, a], f[c, b], f[c, c], f[c, d], f[c, e],
>  f[d, a], f[d, b], f[d, c], f[d, d], f[d, e],
>  f[e, a], f[e, b], f[e, c], f[e, d], f[e, e]}
> ```

Symbol `f @@@ expr` is a shorthand for `Apply[ f, expr, {1}]`. `Tuples[L, 2 ]` generates all pairs of elements of list `L` ( e.g. `{a,b}` is different from `{b,a}`).

Answer (score 2):

I think you intend to do something like this:

```
L = {a, b, c, d};
f /@ Transpose[{L, L}]
```

> {f[{a, a}], f[{b, b}], f[{c, c}], f[{d, d}]}

With `/@` a prefix shorthand for the `Map` function.

You might want to look up `KroneckerProduct` in [the manual](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/KroneckerProduct.html). It doesn't work as you seem to think.

```
KroneckerProduct[L, L]
```

> {{a^2, a b, a c, a d}, {a b, b^2, b c, b d}, {a c, b c, c^2, 
>     c d}, {a d, b d, c d, d^2}}